# Sonar qube container cannot authenticate with token

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonarqube, github-actions

I have a sonar qube instance running on localhost:9001 through docker container. I use ngrok to expose it to the internet. I am using github actions to make my pipeline and when I try to connect to that sonarqube using a token(which is stored in github secrets) I get this :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.431 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-25T10:21:48+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.10.0.2594:sonar (default-cli) on project article: Not authorized. Analyzing this project requires authentication. Please provide a user token in sonar.login or other credentials in sonar.login and sonar.password. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I tried hardcoding the token and I still get the same error so the problem is not in how I have stored the token. I don't know what to try to solve this problem any ideas guys???

Comment: How did you put the token to the github action ? It's recomand to use sonar.login.
https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/user-guide/user-account/generating-and-using-tokens/#using-a-token